# Synchronize subtitles in video

Tags: video, voice-recognition, data-synchronization

I have a text file with all the words being spoken in a video in the right order but not with time reference. Is there a way to place subtitles in the video using this text file?

One way I can think of, is using a voice recognition but most algorithms are not that accurate to complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you bias speech recognition to the text you expect to see by specifying the grammar, so the accuracy is getting much much better.

You can learn more about grammars in speech recognition from the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

Complete solution is not available, but should not be hard to build. Long time ago this was integrated into Gaupol subtitle editor:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gaupol/SpeechRecognition

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to do it the way you wrote with zero luck. I created a .lm file using [this tool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html). Here is my [source code](http://justpaste.it/qqh6), here is the [output](http://justpaste.it/qqh5) and here is the [.lm file](http://justpaste.it/qqh8) . I used an mp3 file of the song Starlight of Muse.

Comment: You should have updated the dictionary as well, not just lm.